# ERROR 1426 (42000) at line 20: Too big precision 14

Tags: mysql, database

I have been given an sql file and am trying to import it with MySQL command line. When I type the following

```
C:\Users\MyUser\Desktop\SQL>mysql -u root -p < memory.sql
Enter password: **********
```

I get this error

```
ERROR 1426 (42000) at line 20: Too big precision 14 specified for column 'lastmod'. Maximum is 6
```

SO I opened the sql file in a text editor, changed 14 to 6, try to import again and I get this:

```
ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 20: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'TYPE=MyISAM' at line 16
```

Here are the create tables

```
CREATE TABLE AccessCard (
 ID int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
 personID int(11) NOT NULL default '0',
 cardFormatID int(11) NOT NULL default '0',
 cardNumber char(6) binary default NULL,
 friendNumber bigint(20) default NULL,
 disabled tinyint(1) NOT NULL default '0',
 issueCode int(11) default NULL,
 lastmod timestamp(14) NOT NULL,
 lastmodPersonID int(11) default NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY  (ID),
 UNIQUE KEY Alter_Key1 (cardFormatID,cardNumber),
 KEY AI_ID (ID),
 KEY IX_cardFormatToAccessCard (cardFormatID),
 KEY IX_PersonToAccessCard (personID)
 ) TYPE=MyISAM;
```

I have googled this and the only thing I found landed me here, but it seemed to be from someone that was creating a new database. I'm fairly new to MySQL, so be gentle. Thanks!

Comment: It'd be helpful if you actually showed the sql. Without it, the error messages are nearly useless, other than to say "yep, your sql is hosed".

Comment: I added the MySQL command I typed, hope thats what you meant.

Comment: No. that's just how you execute the command. We need to see the actual sql. You've basically told your car's repairman "here's how I put the key into the ignition" while he's trying to figure out why the motor won't start.

Comment: If you mean the entire SQL file itself, then I guess I'm SOL, confidential information contained within. Are there lines in particular that would be helpful? Thanks!

Comment: we don't need the data, but the create tables would help. if the field names are sensitive, then change those.

Comment: Gotcha, see edit. Thanks for being patient!

Comment: can't really see anything wrong there. technically you don't need the `(xxx)` stuff after the field types. that's just a display hint to mysql for how many digits/chars you want shown, but internally it has absolutely no effect on storage/field sizing. mysql does prefer `engine=` instead of `type=` now.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This works in MySQL 5.5.32.

```
CREATE TABLE AccessCard (
 ID int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
 personID int(11) NOT NULL default '0',
 cardFormatID int(11) NOT NULL default '0',
 cardNumber char(6) binary default NULL,
 friendNumber bigint(20) default NULL,
 disabled tinyint(1) NOT NULL default '0',
 issueCode int(11) default NULL,
 lastmod timestamp NOT NULL,
 lastmodPersonID int(11) default NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY  (ID),
 UNIQUE KEY Alter_Key1 (cardFormatID,cardNumber),
 KEY AI_ID (ID),
 KEY IX_cardFormatToAccessCard (cardFormatID),
 KEY IX_PersonToAccessCard (personID)
 ) ENGINE=MyISAM;
```

There are two changes.

- Drop the "(14)" from the line `lastmod timestamp NOT NULL,`.
- Change `type=MyISAM` to `ENGINE=MyISAM`. (This might not be necessary on your server. I'm not sure whether this is actually a syntax problem or simply a difference in server configuration.)

There could be a version mismatch or server configuration mismatch here. My version doesn't dump timestamp columns as `timestamp(14)`. My version dumps them as simply `timestamp`.

Comment: OK, Mike's answer got me past that error, now I'm getting another error: ERROR 1426 (42000) at line 1438: Too big precision 14 specified for column 'startDttm'. Maximum is 6. Apparently there are several tables that conflict with the version of MySQL I'm using, which is the most recent. Is there any way to find out which tables aren't supported and change them? Thanks for your help thus far!

Comment: It's just text. If I were in your shoes, I'd use my text editor to chop that SQL file into several logical pieces, and run each piece separately and in order. Verify the database objects before you go to the next file. When you find a syntax error, fix it in all the files, and start over.  In your situation, brute force might be your only friend.

Comment: OK, I did what you suggested and it seems to have worked, I pipe the sql file in, get no errors, but when I enter "use test ;" into the command line, then "show tables ;", I get "Empty set (0.00 sec)" Is my sql file hosed?

Comment: Are you creating the database objects in "test"?  And did you check the result of "use test" and "show tables" after each file?

Comment: Please forgive my ignorance, but how can I tell the name of where the database objects are located. I am literally following a tutorial on Lynda.com to extract the data and it used the name "test". The name of my sql file is memory1.sql if that helps.

Comment: Read the SQL file. Look for a "CREATE DATABASE" statement.